# How to change color of a part of text from < to >

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm making a TextEditor and I need to change the color of the tags from when `<` starts until it closes `>` and need to repeat the tag when closed. kinda like the auto completion.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Winforms, WPF, UWP,..? Please tag accordingly, the methods will be highly dependent on that

Comment: @HansKeﬆing sry i didnt know. Winforms